# Store additional information during registration with Firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I tried to create a user using Firebase Auth by sending an email and a password. Now I want to store the first name and last name after a user is created. Since I am new to Android and Firebase, I just don't see how to do that. Can anyone help me on this?

My code:

```
public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseAuth auth;
Button cancel, submit;
EditText email, password, firstName, lastName;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    firstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstName);
    lastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastName);

    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String inputEmail = email.getText().toString().trim();
            String inputPassword = password.getText().toString().trim();
            registerUser();
        }
    });
}

private void registerUser(){
    final String inputFirstName = firstName.getText().toString();
    String inputLastName = lastName.getText().toString();
    final String inputEmail = email.getText().toString();
    String inputPassword = password.getText().toString();

    progressDialog.setMessage("Registering..");
    progressDialog.show();

    //create user
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(inputEmail, inputPassword)
            .addOnCompleteListener(RegistrationActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {                      
                        Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "User created successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressDialog.hide();
                        startActivity(new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to store the info?

Comment: After a user is created using createUserWithEmailAndPassword(), I want to create a node named "user". Under user, I want to store first name, last name, email and password.

Comment: Ok, where is the problem? Just get the data and save them in firebase.

Comment: There are also other information like website, info etc. that will further be added in a user information. By making a User class, I cannot pass the data in User constructor as all these data might not be sent at once. So I just don't get it on how to store such data.

Comment: Just use setters methods to add the data.

Comment: cna you please show me an example or anything?

Comment: You can see my answer with a simple example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a user class like this:

```
public class User{

 String name;
 String surname;
 String website;
 ....

 public User(){
   // Default constructor required
 }

 public void setName(String name){this.name = name;}
 public void setSurname(String surname){this.surname = surname;}
 public void setWebsite(String website){this.website = website;}

 public String getName(){ return name; }
 .....

}
```

Then just use it:

```
User user = new User();
user.setName("xxxx");
user.setSurname("xxxx");
user.setWebsite("xxxx");

mDatabase.child("users").push().setValue(user);
```

Comment: In JavaScript, there is a way to send all the data as a JSON object at once. Is there any way that I can do so in Java so is it the only way?

Comment: @sangeeta Your question was in java... in any case you can do it in many ways and in many languages. For js check: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: No I was only thinking if there is any other way. I am trying to do it in Android. Anyway I got the idea. Thank you for the help.

Comment: mark the answer if it solves your issue. It can help other users.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti What is `mDatabase`? How last line relate these additional info to current user signing up?

Comment: @ibubi Just `FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();`