# Get parent node from child node in Firebase Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[firebase console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5dub.png)

I want to display current user data like name, email ,phone in three different text view but every time some data is display like email but while fetching two another data it is showing like null in text view  how to solve it.

Comment: Check this link. It will be helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56249121/how-to-retrieve-and-display-data-from-users-that-are-logged-in-firestore

Comment: Can you show some code of getting data ?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank van Puffelen asked for, and please also respond with @.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.