# About register user with firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angular8

Im triying to use firebase in my app but I have a doubt about registration process, I declared an User collection, but when I sign up with google or facebook, the data is stored in Authentication, I want create an user but besides the fiels email and  password, also with a fields like address, role, city and use the createUserWithEmailAndPassword method , to create the user with all those fields, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, you can write code to create a document in Firestore when a user signs in for the first time.  Are you having a problem with that?

Comment: You'll have to write your own code to do that. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/46657445 for a list of links (many of them for Realtime Database, but they can easily be ported to Cloud Firestore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auth only creates it's own entry to its own table. so you should first get these details from the user and send them to user collection manually.

You can create a new user object adding all these details into it and call this:

```
this.fireStore.collection("users")
      .doc(user.id)
      .set(user);
```

Due to security reasons, I wouldn't recommend storing the password in the db though.